# Get element of arrayList using JNI

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am using OpenCV to compute some algorimths, but now i want to convert its into java code, in java code, my program has a method:

```
public native float[] computeFeatures(ArrayList<float[]> listData);
```

now, i am using javah to generate header file and in jni, this method is look like:

```
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_cspdemo_CSPTest_computeFeatures (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject);
```

How do i get elements (each float array such as listData1 = {1,3,4,0};) of listData coressponding in JNI? please help me, thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `size` method for obtaining the number of arrays in the collection.

Then use the `get` method for obtaining an array, in a loop.

Then, for each array, use the `GetFloatArrayElements`JNI API.